# Poisson Random Variable Exact and Approximate Probability

Tags: statistics

Can anyone explain how to approximate probabilities? The previous question was to compute the ***exact*** probability that $X$ is less than $4$ for which I got: $0.1512$. Now instead of the exact probability I have to solve the problems below which are approximations. How would I go about this?

Suppose that $X$ is a Poisson random variable with $\lambda=6$:

(b) Approximate the probability that $X$ is less than four.

(c) Approximate the probability that $8 < X < 12$.

Comment: Guess a probability value of $1/2$ and your error is no more than $0.5$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal distribution to approximate the poisson distribution. Let $X \sim Poi(6)$. The approximation then is

$P(X\leq x)=\Phi \left(\frac{x+0.5-\mu}{\sigma} \right)$

$\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution. And $+0.5$ is the continuity correction factor.

The expected value of $X$ is $\lambda=6$ and the standard deviation of $X$ is $\sqrt{\lambda}=\sqrt{6}$

$P(X\leq 3)\approx\Phi \left(\frac{3+0.5-6}{\sqrt{6}} \right)=\Phi(-1.020621)$

The result of [this  calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx) is $0.15372$

You can also use a [table](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf) and get the value of $\Phi(-1.02)=0.1562$

For c) the approximation is

$P(8<X<12)=P(9\leq X \leq 11)=P(X\leq 11)-P(X\leq 8)$

**Remark**

The accuracy of the approximation may not be enough for some purposes. The reason is that the value of $\lambda$ is not very high. One rule of thumb for a sufficent accurancy is that $\lambda$ has to be greater than $10$.

Comment: No comparison with the actual values (that is, 0.151203883 in the first case)?

Comment: It always depends on the accuracy you want or need, The accuracy of 9 decimal places doesn´t really help.

Comment: Nine decimal places are offtopic but comparing the approximate values you got (0.15372 and 0.1562) to the correct answer (0.15120 and 0.1512 respectively) seems very much ontopic.

Comment: One rule of thumb is that $\lambda$ has to be greater than $10$. Therefore  it is not surprisingly that the approximation is not very well.

Comment: Perfect, just include these considerations into your answer.